# How do I buffer an input when it's float + char [C programming]

Tags: c

I have a simple section of a "money" program which needs to validate the user input and print a rounded float value (to a unit of 10, but must have 2 decimal places) and I was only able to successfully buffer out: char, char mixed with float, negative floats but not **float mixed with char (this always extracts out the float and prints it)** instead of treating the whole input as wrong. Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double amount; /* Input: how much a customer paid */
    int error;   /* Flag: indicate if an error has happened during input */
    int status;  /* Number of successful inputs processed by scanf */

    /* Get a amount due (repeat input if invalid) */
    do {
        error = 0;
        printf("Enter amount due: ");
        status = scanf("%lf", &amount);

        /* if input was not number (probably character(s)) */
        if (status != 1) {
            error = 1;
            printf("  Incorrect input! Enter again.\n");
            while ((getchar()) != '\n');    /* remove input */
        }

        /* input was an integer, but it was outside the valid range */
        else if (amount < 0) {
            error = 1;
            printf("  Amount must be positive! Enter again.\n");
        }
    } while (error);

    printf("The amount due is %0.1f0\n", amount);

    return(0);
}
```

E.g:
Output:

```
Enter amount due: fh32
Incorrect input! Enter again.

Enter amount due: -221.35
Amount must be positive! Enter again.

Enter amount due: 78.57ehwj
The amount due is 78.60
```

And is there a proper programming way (probably) to round off to a unit of 10, but must have 2 decimal places?

for example below code...

```c
printf("Enter amount due: ");
status = scanf("%lf", &amount);
    --------
printf("The amount due is %.1f0\n", amount);
```

...is designed to round off to one decimal place, then 'add' a zero but it only gives correct results sometimes:

Output:

```
Enter amount due: 35.56
The amount due is 35.60

Enter amount due: 35.55
The amount due is 35.50  [wrong]

Enter amount due: 35.25
The amount due is 35.20  [wrong]
```

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). It's you that are "wrong", not the computer.

Comment: If you have multiple questions, ask multiple questions.

Comment: For the latter question, the dupe target solves it. For the former, you can just check if there is anything after the float.